# jQuery hide if clicked outside the button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show a paragraph by clicking on the button with the jQuery. But when it is visible, then I want to hide it by clicking anywhere else than the button (ie. anywhere outside the button).
For example, here is my code:

```
<p style="display: none">Hello  world</p>
<button>Say Hello</button>
```

jQuery:

```
$("button").click(function () {
    $("p").show();
});
```

here is jsfiddle link:
http://jsfiddle.net/k9mUL/

How can I hide it by clicking outside the button? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could bind a `click` event handler to the `document`, as well as the one on the button. In that event handler, hide the `p` element:

```
$("button").click(function (e) {
    $("p").show();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
$(document).click(function() {
    $("p").hide();  
});
```

You need to stop the propagation of the `click` event in the `button` click event, otherwise it will bubble up to the `document` and the `p` element will be hidden again straight away.

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/k9mUL/3/).

Answer (score 3):

You can take advantage of event bubbling by binding your handler to the `click` event of the document and using [event.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) to determine if the user clicked the button or something else in the document:

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
    if ($(event.target).is("button")) {
        $("p").show();
    } else {
        $("p").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: This `if ($(event.target).is("button"))` helped me right now. It's so fantastic. jQuery overall is really precious! How could one live without it... :D

Answer (score 1):

Although doing it manually is great, there is a plugin which allows you to add this functionality of it helps you:

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-outside-events-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

You can bind an event handler to the `click` event on the whole document and check if the targeted element is not a button:

```
$(document).click(function(e){
    if(e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() != 'button')
        $('p').hide();
});
```

Or here's a more "jquery" way :

```
 $(document).click(function(e){
    if(!$(e.target).is('button'))
        $('p').hide();
});
```

Live [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gion_13/k9mUL/2/).

Answer (score 0):

```
<p style="display: none">Hello  world</p>
<button onclick='show(event);'>Say Hello</button>

function show(e){
   $("p").show();
   e.cancelBubble = true;
   document.addEventListener('click',hide,false);
}

function hide(){
   $("p").hide();
  document.removeEventListener('click',hide,false);
}
```

Comment: please don't use inline js :(. it's bad & ugly